# Sorting Dates and serial number

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

```
Date                        SrNo
SEL/2016APR01/002/000001    01
SEL/2016APR02/002/000001    04
SEL/2016APR03/002/000001    03
SEL/2016JAN01/002/000001    02
```

I need to sort the first column Date part(2016JAN01) in Descending order and if there are two same dates then I need to sort the second column in Descending order.

`substr('SEL/2016APR01/002/000001', 4,12)` gives me `2016APR01` but I dont know how to sort dates of that format.

My query looks something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY substr(Date) DES, SrNo DESC
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider storing this data in a more sensible way with each part of that data in its own column Then it would be a breeze

Comment: Why on Earth did you tag your question MySQL if you are using SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

This first answer covers SQL Server, while the answer belows it is for MySQL.  You originally tagged your question MySQL, and so everyone answered for that.

For SQL Server you can use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME,
                 SUBSTRING(Date, 12, 2) + ' ' +
                 SUBSTRING(Date, 9, 3) + ' ' +
                 SUBSTRING(Date, 5, 4),
                 106) DESC,
         SrNo DESC
```

If you were actually using MySQL, then [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) would be the way to go:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Date, 4, 12), '%Y%b%d') DESC,
         SrNo DESC
```

Here is what the formatting parameters mean:

```
%Y - four digit year
%b - three letter month (e.g. JAN, APR)
%d - two digit day of month
```

If the upper case format of the month names results in `STR_TO_DATE` not working, you can try the following (which is admittedly a bit ugly):

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(
             CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Date, 5, 4),
                    SUBSTRING(Date, 9, 1),
                    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Date, 10, 2)),
                    SUBSTRING(Date, 12, 2)),
             '%Y%b%d') DESC,
         SrNo DESC
```

As @RiggsFolly mentioned, your life would made easier if you stored your dates in a standard MySQL format.

Comment: mySQL returns null i think due to case of APR

Comment: mySQL is returining NULL

Comment: it says STR_TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: I am not using mysql. I am using sqlsrv

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(substr(Date, 4,12)), '%Y%b%d') DESC, SrNo DESC`

Answer (score 0):

use STR_TO_DATE FUNCTION

```
SELECT *
    FROM tablename
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Date, 4, 12), '%Y%b%d') , SrNo DESC
```